# How to process a template and remove all bindings from it?

Tags: angularjs

I need to create a page with AngularJS that will display thousands of log entries. These entries will be created with the help of Angular templates, but, since they are unchangeable once printed, I would like to have the bindings removed from the resulting entries.

Is this possible? I looked at $compile (keeps the bindings) and $interpolate (doesn't do directives if I understood correctly, only does {{ }} ) and haven't found an answer to my question.

How would you approach such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the directives defined in the [Bind Once](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) library in order to perform binding for immutable data.

Comment: Since then, bindonce can now replace ng-if as well. I'm accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer to my problem, the problem though can be circumvented with an "infinite scroller" such as the one described here: https://medium.com/p/463bc649c7bd that "disappears" log entries that aren't in the viewable window.